# How do I clean the installed java programs from the Blackberry simulator?

Tags: blackberry

How do I clean the installed java programs from the Blackberry simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run clean.bat file from the "simulator" folder located on your installation path

```
C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0\simulator
```

Or if you are using BB plugin for eclipse then it must be under foll.path

```
C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.16\components\simulator
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-setting/cleaning the simulator isn't always easy. I've tried several times to debug this, but I end up doing the following steps to clean up my simulator(s):

1. Run clean.bat. If that doesn't work, then step #2.
2. I try to manually remove files from the simulator directory. If my application was called "SampleApp", I try to delete anything named "SampleApp.*". If that doesn't work, then step #3.
3. Uninstall, then re-install the simulator or plug-in. I keep clean copies of simulators and/or plugins on my local drive.

As stated elsewhere, your simulator directories are located:

```
C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0\simulator
```

or if using Eclipse:

```
C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.16\components\simulator
```

By the way, have you looked at *clean.bat*? It's the craziest thing. "*Let's change the file permissions of files we think we know, and then try to delete files that we think need to be deleted, and let's run for a very long time, and silently die.*" Nice.

Thanks RIM.